# std::function and lambda expression from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, lambda, std, std-function

I'm working on a translation of some C# code to C++. Since it's the first time I work with C++ there are some things I don't understand.

The structure of the original code in C# is:

```
public static Func<int, int, double> MyFunc(double InVar1, double InVar2)
        {
            return (FunVar1, FunVar2) =>
            {
                double Sum = FunVar1 + FunVar2:
                double Prod = Sum * InVar1 * InVar2; 

                return Prod;
            };
        }
```

The code I tried to replicate in C++ is:

```
std::function<double(int, int)> MyFunc(double InVar1, double InVar2)
{
    return [InVar1,InVar1](int FunVar1, int FunVar2)
    {
         double Sum = FunVar1 + FunVar2:
                double Prod = Sum * InVar1 * InVar2; 

                return Prod;
    };
}
```

First of all I'm not sure if the C++ structure replicates the C# one.
After that I'm getting an error on the capture-list:
`C++ no suitable user-defined conversion from "type" to "[...]" exists` 
I also tried to put in the capture-list:

```
[]
```

```
[&]
```

```
[=]
```

But none of them worked.

Comment: Which C++ compiler do you use? Is the error message really related to the shown code? There is no `type` there.

Comment: I rolled back because a question should not be changed to invalidate exisiting answers.

Answer (score 3):

Code looks ok to me, except that

- you're capturing `InVar1` twice.
- at the end of `double Sum = FunVar1 + FunVar2:` you have a colon instead of a semicolon.

If I fix these errors the code compiles for me:

```
#include <functional>

std::function<double(int, int)> MyFunc(double InVar1, double InVar2)
{
    return [InVar1,InVar2](int FunVar1, int FunVar2)
    {
         double Sum = FunVar1 + FunVar2;
                double Prod = Sum * InVar1 * InVar2; 

                return Prod;
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto f = MyFunc(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

EDIT: On Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/h1YKsPev4

Comment: Sorry those are mistyping. Edited.

Comment: See the working code here: https://godbolt.org/z/h1YKsPev4

Comment: I found the issue btw: I was using several complex type objects and input/output wasn't matching.